# Plain xtable formatting

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I am trying to create a table using Xtable and Rmarkdown. Code is below:

````
```{r xtable, results="asis"}
library(xtable)

data(tli)
table <- xtable(tli[1:10, ])
print(table, type = "html") 
```
````

I expect the following to result in a pretty apa-style table like this:
[image]
What I actually get is the table in a very plain format below: 
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: HTML != PDF; if you want it styled, you'll have to use CSS (or get a function to do so for you).

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. So, if I knit it to a PDF instead of html, then it will look nice?

Comment: Well, yes, but it's a different use-case. If you're knitting in RMarkdown, it's probably easier to use `knitr::kable` or `pander::pander`, which will automatically get a dose of CSS.

Comment: Ok. Just tried out kable and it looks good. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a different package (of which I am the author):

```
library(huxtable)
data(tli)
ht <- as_hux(tli, add_colnames = TRUE)
top_border(ht)[1,] <- 1
bottom_border(ht)[1,] <- 1
bold(ht)[1,] <- TRUE
bottom_border(ht)[nrow(ht),] <- 1
ht
```

should get you what you want when printed in a TeX document.